# Excel: How do I replace text by using a wildcard?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

A1= Blabla,124814012

I want to remove everything but "Blabla".

What command do i use to get the effect as if i did CTRL+H (replace) and told it to replace ",*" with nothing.

I can do it this:
=REPLACE(A1,FIND(",",A1,1),3000,"")

But need to be able to do it using x* etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get Morefunc Addon and use:

`=REGEX.SUBSTITUTE(A1 , ",(.*)" , "")`

---

**MOREFUNC ADDON**

- Morefunc Addon is a free library of 66 new worksheet functions.
- [HERE](http://web.archive.org/web/20111204011358/http://xcell05.free.fr/morefunc/english) is some information (by original author)
- here is the last working [download link](http://www.freewarefiles.com/downloads_counter.php?programid=14922) I found
- here is a good [installation walk-through video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAofPm4LCRc#t=92)

Comment: You'd think microsoft would add regex by now. Thx

Comment: RegEx does exist in VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
Dim x as string
x = range("a1").value
if cbool(instr(1, x, chr(44))) then _
    x = left(x, instr(1, x, chr(44))-1)  'Chr(44) is a comma
debug.print x
```

*Addendum:* I'd make the function version a little fancier.

```
Public Function fc_Split_at(sSTR As String, sDELIM As String, Optional iPC = 1)
    fc_Split_at = Split(sSTR, sDELIM)(iPC - 1)
End Function
```

Syntax:

=fc_Split_at(*<original string>*, *<delimiter>*, [optional]*<piece to return>*)

```
?fc_Split_at("*Blabla,124814012", ",")
*Blabla
?fc_Split_at("*Blabla,124814012", ",", 2)
124814012
```

Comment: Can you make that into a function?
     
=FREPLACE(target,replace what, replace with this)
         
=FREPLACE(A1,",*","")

Comment: Yeah thats pretty cool. Even tough it turned out differently that I thought.

Answer (score 1):

Excel's Find & Replace does allow for wildcard characters.

In your simplified example, if you went to find / replace and typed in:

**Find What:** `Blabla*`

**Replace With:** `Blabla`

That would do the trick and remove anything following `Blabla`.

Hope that does the trick!!

Comment: I was trying to use a formula or udf for it (; And you assume I always replace with nothing (: And I never replace what i have to remove with something else (: Thx any ways tough.